# Hover function after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that shrinks on scroll, the li's in the navbar-nav have an image, when the navbar shrinks on scroll the image stays but the text display becomes none.

I have a function that shows this text on hover after it disappears but i have a problem, i only want this function to work only after the navbar shrinks, and when the navbar goes to it's normal size i don't want this function to work, and another thing i want the function to display the text for each li separately because when i hover it shows all of the spans with the text, i only want the child of the li, i tried the `.children()` method but it didn't work, please help! here is my code:

```js
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
      }
    });

$('.home').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('margin-right', '5px');
   $('.navbar-nav li a span').css('display', 'block');
  $('.navbar-nav li a').css('height', '155px');
  $('.navbar-nav li a img').css('margin-right', '5px');
});
```

```css
 body {
      padding-top: 50px;
      min-height:800px
    }

    nav a {
      padding-top: 20px !important;
      padding-bottom: 20px !important;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    nav .navbar-toggle {
      margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; 
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 30px;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    nav.navbar.shrink {
      min-height: 35px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; 
    }

    nav.shrink a {
      padding-top: 10px !important;
      padding-bottom: 10px !important;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
      padding: 4px 5px;
      margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-nav li a span{
display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active home"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="active service"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>Services</span></a></li>
            <li class="active about"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>About us</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: one option could be that you bind and unbind hover inside your scroll check

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I tried it but it didn't work, can you do it for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve the behaviour you want, you do not need to abuse javascript, of course it can be done with JS, but it is much easier and straightforwad is just to use CSS

just add this rule to your code:

```
nav.shrink .navbar-nav li:hover a span{
  display: block
}
```

this is of course just example, but I am sure that using the CSS approach you will achieve your goal easier, faster and without extra performance overhead=)

Here is a working snippet:

```js
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
      }
    });
```

```css
 body {
      padding-top: 50px;
      min-height:800px
    }

    nav a {
      padding-top: 20px !important;
      padding-bottom: 20px !important;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    nav .navbar-toggle {
      margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; 
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 30px;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    nav.navbar.shrink {
      min-height: 35px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; 
    }

    nav.shrink a {
      padding-top: 10px !important;
      padding-bottom: 10px !important;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
      padding: 4px 5px;
      margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
    }

    nav.shrink .navbar-nav li a span{
display: none
}
nav.shrink .navbar-nav li:hover a span{
display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active home"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="active service"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>Services</span></a></li>
            <li class="active about"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/512/andrew.png" height="50" width="50"><span>About us</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```